# pydantic's filter for the relation destination

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am using fastapi.
There is a simple relation as follows

```
class Parent(Base):
  id: int
 children = relationship(
    "Child",
    backref="parent",
    uselist=True
  )


class Child(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'children'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
  parent.id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Parent.id))
  is_detele = Column(Boolean)

class ParentBase(BaseModel):
  id: int
  children = list

  class Config:
      orm_mode = True
```

If ParentBase is used at this time, nested children can also be obtained, but I would like to filter with data for which is_delete is False.

If you know anything about it, it would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share your query ?

Comment: Since the pydantic models are the schema that describes the output, it's not up to the pydantic model to do the filtering - but your relationship. If you want the relationship to _always_ filter against `is_delete`, you can use the `primaryjoin` argument to `relationship`.

Comment: **parent = db.query(Parent).filter(Parent.id==id)**
I have tried join and filter but all I get in the end is one parent model
Then when I serialize it with pydantic, it returns all the children.

Comment: I looked up primaryjoin.
Looks good.
I'll give it a try.